# Emacs color & font mayhem

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm a long time (26 years) Emacs user, all the way from TECO Emacs to GNU Emacs 23.4 for MacOS X. I can hack Lisp macros and usually find my way around.

Emacs has become very big. And very colorful.

Is there a simple way to make sure that Emacs never changes font size or color ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off all font colours and other decorations with the following line in your .emacs:

```
(global-font-lock-mode 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has some highlighting that is not controlled by `font-lock-mode`.

Here is a [solution](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2007-08/msg00598.html) posted by Juri Linkov to the Emacs Dev mailing list, back in 2007:

```
I use the following trick to post-process faces immediately after they
get created.  I also modified this code to not reset mode line faces:

(defun my-faces-fix (&optional frame)
  "Fix defined faces."
  (interactive)
  ;; Check if this function is called by `custom-define-hook' from
  ;; `custom-declare-face' where the variable `face' is bound locally.
  (when (boundp 'face)
    (dolist (face (face-list))
      (unless (memq face '(mode-line mode-line-highlight mode-line-inactive))
        ;; Reset all face attributes
        (modify-face face)))))

;; 1. Fix existing faces
(let ((face t)) (my-faces-fix))

;; 2. Call `my-faces-fix' every time some new face gets defined
(add-to-list 'custom-define-hook 'my-faces-fix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've been using for two years now:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :height 113 :family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))))
 '(font-lock-builtin-face ((nil (:foreground "#7F0055" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-keyword-face ((nil (:foreground "#7F0055" :weight bold))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((nil (:foreground "#3F7F5F"))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((nil (:foreground "#2A00FF"))))
 '(font-lock-type-face ((t (:underline t :slant italic :foreground "#000000"))))
 '(font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground "#110099"))))
 '(font-lock-variable-name-face ((nil nil)))
 '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:weight bold)))))
```

You can customize a bunch of other faces too:
just call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face`. It will auto-select
the current face.